# How to block the auto redirection of websites using curlPHP

Tags: javascript, php

We are doing link validation of html files using PHP.

Where we have lots of links with various domains like .com, .co.in, .ie etc.

If we validate the file with `.com` links, it is being automatically redirected to a `.co.in` page on recognizing the IP address. So how would I  avoid such redirection and how would I go about getting the appropriate domain while navigating the links.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to follow the redirects provided by the HTTP response header, use the following option in your curl request:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

Comment: The links which we are using is encoded, if we put the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION as false, it shouldn't be redirected. so we made that as TRUE. Can u please provide some other solutions.

Comment: " if we put the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION as false, it shouldn't be redirected" That is exactly what you are asking for isn't it?